# "ValueError: could not convert string to float" in Python

Tags: python

I'm getting "could not convert string to float" error while trying to implement the below mentioned code.
In the code, I am basically reading a CSV file and trying to convert the string values (all values are numeric) into float.

```
import csv
def loadCsv(filename):
    lines = csv.reader(open(filename, "rt"))
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset

filename = 'Pima Diabetes.csv'
dataset = loadCsv(filename)
print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows').format(filename, len(dataset))
```

Comment: This is not reproducible, it means that one of the inputs to the float() is not a float.

Comment: I would use a simple tools such as pandas for such problem: `import pandas as pd;df = pd.read_csv('Your_CSV.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

The first row of your dataset contains the names of your features which are basically 'strings'. According to your code, you are converting each line in your dataset to float which also includes the feature names. What you want is to have your code read lines from the second row.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, using csv and open is going the hard way. You could simply

```py
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

# read csv to a data frame 
# sep is default to ','. You can change with sep='\t' for tab,
df = pd.read_csv('YOUR_CSV.csv')

# print the number of rows and columns
print(df.shape)
```